# How to open a link in new tab using selenium python

Tags: python, selenium

Below code is not working for me with IE:

```
ele=driver.find_element_by_link_text("Search Tickets")
ele.send_keys(Keys.CONTROL + 't')
```

-------------------------OR---------------------------------

```
link=ele.click()
link=send_keys(Keys.CONTROL+'t')
```

By clicking on "Search Tickets" I have to open this in new tab instead it is going to new window....

Answer (score 0):

You can open link in new tab by this command:

```
driver.execute_script('''window.open("http://google.com","_blank");''')
```

And to get link from element use something like this:

```
element = driver.find_element_by_link_text("Search Tickets")
link = element.get_attribute("href")
```